# Dynamic displays correctly in debugger but fails when try to access values

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a strange issue. I've a method that expects an `IEnumerable` of `dynamic` that later I have to iterate to do some things.

The code that invokes the method is this:

```
GuardarControlCristalesPedidos(
    items.Select(o => new {o.Id, o.CantidadRecibida, o.Cerrado}));
```

This method is coded as

```
public static void GuardarControlCristalesPedidos(IEnumerable itemsAGuardar)
{
    var session = FactoryProvider.GetCurrentSession();
    using (var t = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
         foreach (dynamic item in itemsAGuardar)
         {
              var cItem = session.Load<PedidoItem>(item.Id);
              cItem.CantidadRecibida = item.CantidadRecibida;
              cItem.Cerrado = item.Cerrado;
              session.Save(cItem);
         }
         t.Commit();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I have is that the program fails throwing `'item.Id' produjo una excepción de tipo 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

But strangely, when I access the `dynamic` variable with the debugger it seems to be fine (the IDE displays the members fine, but fails when I try to access `item.Id`

[image: Dynamic Debugger Watch]

What is happening here?

Comment: Using dynamic is a bad option. use proper type. What is type of itemsAGuardar (this is list of which type)? Use that type instead of dynamic.

Comment: Yes, surely I will end using a strong type... But I just curious of this strange situation

Comment: may be some problem occur in casting. Not sure.

Comment: The correct answer can be found here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316344/dynamic-object-runtime-reports-field-not-present-but-can-see-it-in-debugger

Answer (score 0):

This probably will be working:

```
var cItem = session.Load<PedidoItem>((int)item.Id);
```

Comment: Nope... the exception is throwed when trying to access `item.Id`, so the cast will never work